# Error en TextBox VB

Tags: visual-studio

Cuando le doy click al boton Guardar me arroja el siguiente error: **'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'**.

El boton Guardar por el momento solo esconde todos los elementos inecesarios.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

El codigo de los texboxs son los siguientes:

```
Private Sub ResultadoPrueba2_1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtResultadoPrueba2_1.TextChanged
    'Try
    If txtResultadoPrueba2_1.Text = 1 Then
            PassPrueba2_1.Show()
            ContinuarPrueba2_2.Show()
        Else
            If txtResultadoPrueba2_1.Text = 0 Then
                FailPrueba2_1.Show()
                Guardar.Show()
            End If
        End If
    'Catch ex As Exception
    'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás comparando un tipo string (el texto de la caja de texto) con un tipo numérico. Debes compararlo como tal, cambiando `= 1` por `= "1"`:

```
If txtResultadoPrueba2_1.Text = "1" Then
        PassPrueba2_1.Show()
        ContinuarPrueba2_2.Show()
    Else
        If txtResultadoPrueba2_1.Text = "0" Then
            FailPrueba2_1.Show()
            Guardar.Show()
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.